# How to show marker on buffer and show the info on click of that marker ArcGIS JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

First for creating the buffer the below function is used

```
function custombuffer(radial,latt,longt,zoomlevel) {

        map.graphics.clear();
        var pt = new Point(Number(longt), Number(latt), new SpatialReference({
                                wkid: 4326
                            }));
                             map.centerAndZoom(pt,zoomlevel);
        var params = new esri.tasks.BufferParameters();
        params.geometries = [pt];
        //buffer in linear units such as meters, km, miles etc.
        params.distances = [radial];

        params.unit = esri.tasks.GeometryService.UNIT_KILOMETER;
        params.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
        gsvc.buffer(params, showBuffer);


    }
    function showBuffer(geometries) {
        var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(
                esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(
                    esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                    new dojo.Color([0, 255, 0, 0.1]), 2),
                new dojo.Color([0, 0, 255, 0.2]));

        dojo.forEach(geometries, function (geometry) {
            var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry, symbol);
            map.graphics.add(graphic); 
            //map.centerAndZoom(pt,10);

        });
    }
```

and then I hit the webservice to get the lattitude and longtitude to
create the marker inside the buffer which is created using above
function.

Here is the code:

```
  $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "app_code/pointdata.php?filtervalue="+filtervalue+"&filtertype="+filtertype+"&latt="+latt+"&longt="+longt+"&radial_dist="+radial_dist,
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (dat) {
                    var dataPoint = JSON.parse(dat.trim());
                    for (var i = 0; i < dataPoint.length; i++) {
                if (dataPoint[i].longitude && dataPoint[i].latitude) {
                    var pt = new Point(Number(dataPoint[i].longitude), Number(dataPoint[i].latitude), new SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 }));
                 //   var markersymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol('images/marker.png', 10, 15);
                   var content = '<table>';
                    content += "<tr><td><b>test</td></b>" + "<td><b>,</b></td><td>test</td></tr>";

                    var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate('Point info', content);
                    polygraphlayer.add(new Graphic(pt, markersymbol, attr, infoTemplate));


                 // polygraphlayer.add(new Graphic(pt, markersymbol));
            }
             }
```

buffer and marker are created successfully but the problem is when I
try to click the marker its simply zoom in the buffer. I want to show
the content info on that marker